# problem running migrations to new Heroku Postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to deploy my backend to Heroku. I've pushed the app to heroku and it is supposedly working. I'm trying to run typeorm:migration:run however I get error during migration run:

error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.90.xx.xxx", user "blahblahblah", database "blahblah", SSL off

my app.module.ts code includes the following:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        url: configService.get('DATABASE_URL'),
        ssl: {
            required: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        },
        entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
        synchronize: false,
    }),
}),
```

I don't understand why the connection error says "SSL off." I'm quite inexperienced with all of this, so I may be missing something completely obvious.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create env variables like this: PGSSLMODE=no-verify